# Sequence of digits to be printed_Need help on why '2' becomes third in order

Tags: java, static, initialization, instantiation

```
class A{
   public A() { }
   public A(int i) {   System.out.println(i );    }
}
class B{
   static A s1 = new A(1);
   A a = new A(2);
   public static void main(String[] args){
      B b = new B();
      A a = new A(3);
   }
   static A s2 = new A(4);
}
```

Ouput -> 1 4 2 3

Query -> First two numbers displayed in order of being static class initialisation

But have a query on what basic '2' gets printed. Could see the statement 'A a = new A(2);' which is declared as field for class B and not inside main method.

Could somebody help on how the third number '2' got the next priority after static variable.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the constructor of A and look at the stack trace each time you hit it.

Comment: What did you expect? You created an instance of `B`, so of course `B`'s instance fields, such as `a`, are going to be initialised. And initialising `a` involves calling `new A(2)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two static initialisers in class B, so when that class is ran, those two will be executed first in order, so `static A s1 = new A(1);` will print out 1 and then `static A s2 = new A(4);` will print 4. Then the code within your main method will start to execute. The first line in your main method is `B b = new B();`. This creates a new object of class B and in doing so will call `A a = new A(2);` which will cause 2 to be printed to the console. Then you call `A a = new A(3);` which prints 3 to the console. And there you have it and output of
1
4
2
3

Comment: To be precise, when a static method belonging to B is called, the two static fields are initialised.